# Is there a online website to forward incoming emails to a other emails?

Tags: php, email, online

I created a PHP program that receives emails from clients, then I *manually* forward the client's email to around 50 suppliers.

Is there a possibility or an online website, so that when a client sends me an email it is forwarded automatically to 50 suppliers?

Comment: If your PHP script is already receiving (and presumably processing) these emails then isn't possible to adapt your script to then forward these emails as well?

Answer (score 1):

Almost all the web-hosting provider provides the facility of email forwarding.

Log into your webhosting:

In the Cpanel see the mail section, click on Forwaders option. Here you can forward the mail to as many people you wish.

But I would suggest to get the mail from your client forwarded to any of your Gamil account. Forwarding from a Gmail account is much easier and there is many filtering option also.